# Деплой проекта на сервер. Использую Django-Gunicorn-Supervisor

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

При запуске проекта через гуникорн (`gunicorn quiz.wsgi:application --bind 64.227.71.171:8000`) все работает, выдает начальную nginx страницу по айпишнику сервера. Однако при попытке запустить супервизор сразу же возникает проблема: `quiz                             FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)` Структуру директорий можете видеть на [гитхабе](https://github.com/arturchique/Quiz) (есть папка репозитория Quiz, а внутри папка джанго-проекта quiz).

quiz.conf файл (на сервере /home/john/Quiz/quiz/config/quiz.conf):

```
[program:quiz]
command=/home/john/venv/bin/gunicorn quiz.wsgi:application -c /home/john/Quiz/quiz/config/gunicorn.config.py
directory=/home/john/Quiz/quiz
user=john
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/john/Quiz/quiz/logs/debug.log
```

В debug.log прописана кучу раз одна строчка и ничего больше:

```
...
Error: '/home/john/Quiz/quiz/config/gunicorn.config.py' doesn't exist   
Error: '/home/john/Quiz/quiz/config/gunicorn.config.py' doesn't exist   
...
```

Запускаю на Debian10 сервере, пути к гуникорну прописаны верно:

```
john@quiz:~/Quiz/quiz/config$ ls
gunicorn.conf.py  quiz.conf
```

Comment: Читайте stdout_logfile, очевидно

Comment: @andreymal , исправила вопрос, пока исправляла, нашла ошибку, спасибо)))

Comment: @andreymal Я исправила путь к файлу, перезапустила supervisor (```supervisorctl reread   supervisorctl update ``` также попробовала restart), но ничего не изменилось, а ошибки в дебагере всё те же