# Деплой проекта на Debian сервер. Проблемы с supervisor

Tags: python, django, развертывание, gunicorn, supervisord

Я деплою приложение django-gunicorn-supervisor. При запуске проекта через гуникорн (`gunicorn quiz.wsgi:application --bind 64.227.71.171:8000`) все работает, выдает начальную nginx страницу по айпишнику сервера.

При первом запуске supervisor была ошибка:

```
FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

о ней он сообщил в debug.log (`Error: '/home/john/Quiz/quiz/config/gunicorn.config.py' doesn't exist`), тогда я неправильно прописала путь к gunicorn.

Вот мой исправленный quiz.conf файл:

```
[program:quiz]
command=/home/john/venv/bin/gunicorn quiz.wsgi:application -c /home/john/Quiz/quiz/config/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/home/john/Quiz/quiz
user=john
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/john/Quiz/quiz/logs/debug.log
```

Теперь же ошибка исправлена, а supervisor продолжает спамить все ту же самую ошибку в дебагер. Я перезапускал supervisor (`restart`, `reload`, `stop+start`), делал `reread+update`, но он продолжает выдавать все ту же самую ошибку, одинаково описывая ее в дебагере. Я даже удалила и заново установила supervisor, но ошибка остается такой же.

Как можно это исправить???

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Деплой проекта на сервер. Использую Django-Gunicorn-Supervisor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162358/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e-django-gunicorn-supervisor)

Comment: @dIm0n там спрашивала, как найти ошибку в config файле. Сейчас спрашиваю, как исправить supervisor, чтобы он увидел обновления в конфиг файле

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Файл .conf можно напрямую изменять в самом supervisor. Для этого нужно перейти в директорию:

`cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d/`

Далее любым редактором исправляем файл прямо на сервере и уже не применяем `reread`, а просто делаем `supervisorctl update`. Должно заработать.